# Which configuration for "dynamic" images in GWT/GAE (cache, public folder...)?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, gwt, caching

First, I do not know what I should understand when we talk about "dynamic images"... but in my website (talk about movies - www.mananaseguro.com) I have to display the poster of each movie. So I think these images are considered dynamic images.

I do not know:

1. If these images should be in the cache, and if yes what expiration date (GAE)?
2. If these images should be in the public folder (GWT)?
3. How to correctly refer to these images, I use `setUrl("./MananaSeguro/posters/p1.gif")` (GWT)?
4. If my APPLICATION_SPRITE (that have all UI images) be in the cache (GAE)?
5. I do not like  to have all these images in `./client/resources/` directory. Is it possible to have them in the WAR directory to be more conformtable (if yes, how to configure it)?
6. After that, I will use OBJECTIFY for my database, but the same kind of question occurs : 
   Do you know in wich directory would I need to store these images (I will need to refer to their path inside the database)?
7. I do not know GAE, but do you know if there is an interesting feature to store these images (Blobstore)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not sure if you're talking about Google memcache service or browser cache. The images should be stored in the browser cache (the required headers will be set by the image service when the images are served). The images should not be stored in the memcache service, that's for storing data that is fetched regularly and/or is expensive to fetch or calculate.
2. The public (I assume you mean "war"?) folder  is for static content, not dynamic. You'd need to re-deploy your application each time a movie was added if you stored movie images here.
3. The [Images service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/) generates serving URLs from blobstore keys. These are the URLs you pass to setUrl on  the client.
4. The application sprite image should go in the public folder as it's static.
5. [This page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig) describes how to specify which files/paths should be served statically from the WAR
6. The dynamic images will be stored in the blobstore, so you just need to keep the blobstore key to retrieve them
7. Yes the blobstore is what you're after. With the Images API doing a lot of the "heavy lifting" for you.

Comment: Hi NickTee, great answer ! 

1. I was talking about the browser cache. cf. WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml. Here I can set the expiration date (

<static-files>
<include path="dyna_img/**.jpg" expiration="30d" />
</static-files>)

Can you confirm me that is what I need to write ?

2. I assume that the public folder is the WAR folder, does this mean that all the files inside the WAR folder will be deployed on a directory on the GAE ? I do not know to see theses files that are deployed on my server with a GAE account. Do you know if there is an FTP to connect to my "public" directory?

Thanks you !

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to set the expiry of the dynamic images in the static images configuration, is that correct? If so, that won't work. The URLs generated by the image service use long hexadecimal paths to identify the image. The images service uses Etags and If-None-Match request/response headers to control caching by clients (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag). So you don't need to worry about it. If the image changes, the fresh one will be sent to the client.

Comment: An example of an image served by the image service can be found here http://lh6.ggpht.com/0Bcqof2M4K5PAqzFkxZLLWakbpZ53H1b5za51ZFSj_Ste2Pxz8Rh0JZkf2tuD6g-bWcB3uttVZyU_j2u5enqqj1ZONWsiw2Vag=s640. Look at the headers that are set, try clearing your cache and see the request/response headers that result using Firebug. Notice the =s640 on the end of the URL, it's the image service's way of specifying the maximum pixel dimension. Very useful for thumbnails & layouts.

Comment: As for your second question, by default everything in the WAR (except WEB-INF I think) is a static file. You change this default by using the <static-files> directive. There's no FTP service to browse the static content, but you can just put together HTTP requests to test your assumptions.